# unknown column in filed list - jpa

Tags: jpa, playframework-1.x

I get this error with play framework 1.2.4

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions - Unknown column 'mytable0_.id' in 'field list'
```

My Model is

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="mytable")
public class MyTable extends Model{
    @Id
    public BigInteger pid;
    public String ip;
    ...

}
```

where pid is primary key

I tried extending from GenericModel but that gave same error.

I am trying to obtain pid from MyTable based on a particular ip, using this in my controller

```
List<MyTable> currentIP = MyTable.find("select a from MyTable a where ip = '" + SelectedIP + "'").fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Model` already declares a property named `id` for primary key.

If you want to declare your own `@Id`, you need to extend `GenericModel` instead:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="mytable")
public class MyTable extends GenericModel { ... }
```

Comment: If I use GenericModel then I get `Exception in thread "main" play.exceptions.JPAException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory`